# getting null pointer exception at Location

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

i am new to android.i need to get lattitude and logitude of current location.but it shows null pointer exception in location.here below i added my code.

```
LocationManager lm;
Location location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    SaveLocation(location);


}

private void SaveLocation(Location location) {

    Long time=new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+1*60*1000;
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);

    intent.putExtra("lat",location.getLatitude());
    intent.putExtra("lon",location.getLongitude());

    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));


}
```

my androidmanifasted file is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Post your logcat then.

Comment: you need the current location .

Comment: look at my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673185/setting-double-from-within-locationlistener/19673579#19673579

Answer (score 1):

Your location is null because you instantly try to get the last known location after you create a LocationManager. In this time (some milliseconds) your device can't find any locations.
You need a time gap between your initalization of your LocationManager and the getLastKnownLocation-method. I would recommend to put the getLastKnownLocation-method in an OnClick event on a button to create a time gap.

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>      lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
>      /.... 
> }
>
> button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View v){
>            location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
>            SaveLocation(location);
>       }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Location` object is null, since there is no last known location stored.

```
location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

// Check if last known location exists.
if(location != null) {
    SaveLocation(location);
}
```

Comment: How can i get Location?

Comment: You have to enable your gps and have signal, otherwise it will fail. If you are creating an app you must be aware of the fact that the user sometimes will try to use your app even thought they have no signal. Thus, you always have to check for these nullpointerexceptions so your app does not crash. If you want to test in emulator, you can check out this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Answer (score 0):

```
//to find the current latitude and longitude of user
public String  getMyLocation(){

    locationManager=(LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


    if(location!=null){

        loc[0]=location.getLatitude();
        loc[1]=location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("STATUS n ", loc[0]+"entered 1"+loc[1]);

    }
    else {
        location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if(location!=null)
        {

            loc[0]=location.getLatitude();
            loc[1]=location.getLongitude();
            Log.d("STATUS n","else"+loc[0]+"entered 1"+loc[1] );
        }

    }
    return getPlace(loc);
}
```