# Maps doesn't get current location

Tags: android, google-maps

When I start my app which has a map on it, it should get the device's current location and focus the map to that location, but it doesn't. This is the way I do it:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);

    checkMap();
    return view;
}

private void checkMap() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        /*Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment*/
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        /*Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.*/
        if (mMap != null) {
            initMap();
        }
    }
}

private void initMap() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    /*Get last known location*/
    defaultLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    /*If it doesn't exist, update once*/
    if (defaultLocation == null) {
        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                defaultLocation = location;
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }
        }, getActivity().getMainLooper());
    }
    /*When we get the location, focus the map on it*/
    if (defaultLocation != null) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(defaultLocation.getLatitude(), defaultLocation.getLongitude()), 5));
    }
}
```

I'm not getting an issue, it just doesn't focus the map on the current location. What I'm doing wrong?

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
    Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />       
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="...KEY..."/>
```

Comment: Have you checked defaultLocation variable? is it null or not? are you sure?

Comment: @pratt it doesn't focus the map over the location so it must be null

Comment: do you have the necessary permissions in the manifest? Are you testing in an emulator that might have dummy gps coordinates?

Comment: @masmic ya so you know already that it must be null then you must need to know that where is the problem. Dont wait for someone spoon feed you, try it with your self.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673185/setting-double-from-within-locationlistener/19673579#19673579

Comment: @tiago7 manifest permissions added. I'm testing on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Code:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        for (String provider : providers) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,
                    new LocationListener() {
                        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        }

                        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        }

                        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        }

                        public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                                int status, Bundle extras) {
                        }
                    });
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location != null) {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng= location.getLongitude();

            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( new LatLng( lat, lng), 15));
            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
         googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 1500, null);
}
}
```

it work for me.
Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are getting proper latitude longitude or not, you can print latitude and longitude and Try This.

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); // put your lat long here

CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);

googleMap.moveCamera(center);
googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (defaultLocation != null) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(defaultLocation.getLatitude(), defaultLocation.getLongitude()), 5));
    }
```

To inside the `requestSingleUpdate` listener:

```
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            defaultLocation = location;
             mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(defaultLocation.getLatitude(), defaultLocation.getLongitude()), 5));
        }
```